# MLE of covariate parameter

Tags: r, estimation, inverse, mle

Hi I'm currently doing coding to simulate data using inverse method. Im using parallel exponential model where I let the lambda=b0+b1x. My simulation is based on survival analysis.

```
#generate data
gen <- function(n,lambda,b0,b1){
   set.seed(1)
   
   u <- runif(n,0,1)
   c1 <- rexp(n,lambda)
   x <- rnorm(n,0,1)
   
   t1 = -log(1 - sqrt(u) ) / (b0 + b1*x) #inverse method
   
   c <- 1*(t1 < c1)
   t = pmin(t1, c1)
   
   data1 <- data.frame(x, t, t1, c1, c)
   return(data1)
 }

data2 <- gen(20,0.01,2,4)
data2
x = data2$x
t = data2$t
xsum = sum(x)
tsum = sum(t)
```

The problem is that when run the second coding below, it won't show my `mle` for `b0` and `b1`

```
#Likelihood
library(maxLik)
LLF <- function(para){
  set.seed(1)
  
  b0 = para[1]
  b1 = para[2]
  
  n = 1
  
  z1 = (n*log(2)) + (n*log(b0+b1*xsum)) - ((b0+b1*xsum)*tsum) + (n*log(1-exp((-(b0 + b1*xsum)*tsum))))

  return(z1)
}

mle <- maxLik(LLF, start = c(2,4))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you assigned `n=1` in the `LLF`. Since we usually maximize the parameters given the entire data, `n` should be equal to number of observations. If you update this info, your `mle` will converge. For example,

```
n<-nrow(data2)

#Likelihood
library(maxLik)
LLF <- function(para){
set.seed(1)

b0 = para[1]
b1 = para[2]

#n = 1

z1 = (n*log(2)) + (n*log(b0+b1*xsum)) - ((b0+b1*xsum)*tsum) + (n*log(1-exp((-(b0 + b1*xsum)*tsum))))

return(z1)
}

mle <- maxLik(LLF, start = c(2,4))
summary(mle)

Maximum Likelihood estimation
Newton-Raphson maximisation, 3 iterations
Return code 1: gradient close to zero
Log-Likelihood: -22.7055 
2  free parameters
Estimates:
     Estimate Std. error t value Pr(> t)
[1,]    1.986         NA      NA      NA
[2,]    3.986         NA      NA      NA
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. Now the only problem is the standard error return value NA. z1 should be the log-likelihood right? I am not sure about that part.

Comment: @zira: Nice! Please check on the tickmark icon next to the answer to mark it as answered and give my answer an UpVote. :)

Comment: It's difficult to for me to suggested anything about `z1`, since there is very little information provided on the type of model.